# using regex and match to find pattern in a string C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm New in `Regex` programming and I want to search for a pattern 
example:

19:09:41 PM  :  [  0]  0.0-100.2 sec   796 MBytes  66.6 Mbits/sec   0.273 ms 2454161/3029570 (81%)  --> I want 66

18:55:13 PM  :  [  0]  0.0-99.1 sec  3847 MBytes   326 Mbits/sec   0.068 ms 247494/3029365 (8.2%) --> I want 326

So in the first step i want the **Number** Mbits/sec

This is My code snippet

```
Regex TP_PatternInt = new Regex(@"(?<TP>\d+) Mbit/sec");
Match TP_MatchInt = TP_PatternInt.Match(StringName);
string ResultInt = TP_MatchInt.ToString().Split(' ')[0];

Regex TP_PatternFloat = new Regex(@"(?<TP>\d+).\d Mbit/sec");
Match TP_MatchFloat = TP_PatternFloat.Match(StringName);
string ResultFloat = TP_MatchFloat.ToString().Split(' ')[0];

if (TP_MatchFloat.Success) Return ResultFloat;
else if(TP_MatchInt.Success) return ResultInt;
```

but when I run it I never get `TP_MatchFloat.Success == true`

What am I missing here ? 
Can someone propose a single pattern for both cases ?

**EDIT** added the look of the input string to be more precise

Comment: I came up with this if you want exact matching including groups and only strings with "Mbit/sec" in them: `@"(?<TP>\d+)[.\d]*[ Mbit\/sec]"`.

Comment: I came up with `(\d{1,5})(.\d{1,5})? (K|M|G)bit/(sec|min|hr)` it's most likely not the most efficient solution. You'll need the first result group, you can tune it at regexr.com

Comment: @LordTitiKaka Just some advice, make sure you provide all necessary information up-front. The examples you provide are going to affect all existing answers and this is something you could have presented initially.

Comment: again , you right! I've made a fool out of me

Comment: @lordtitikaka regexr.com is a good place to learn and test regex it helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

Using positive lookahead, you can dispense with groups:

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?= Mbit/sec)
```

So this will match both `66.6` in your first example and `329` in your second, but only if they are followed by `Mbit/sec`.

I suggest removing the fractional part once you've extracted the value by parsing to decimal and using `Math.Floor`.

Comment: This also matches the decimal value, and the OP simply wants the integer. So, 66.6 should capture 66.

Comment: Hmm.. I think it would be better to take the entire value and to parse it as a decimal once extracted.

Comment: @spender Maybe, but it is possible to immediately capture what you want.

Comment: @spender It doesn't work at all , I've just replaced this expression with mine

Comment: please review my update , i have made a mistake and which throw you off

Answer (score 0):

```
 var str = "329 Mbit/sec";
 var regex = new Regex(@"^-?\d+(?:\d+)?(?= Mbit/sec)");
 var match = regex.Match(str);
 if (match.Success)
 {
      var value = decimal.Parse(match.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 }
```

Comment: Again to note, this doesn't constraint to strings with "Mbit/sec" on the end.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Updated now

Comment: please review my question I have made some corrections